# In Genesis 2:22-23 did the material from Adam's side provide Adam's life to Eve or just the material from which she was made?

Tags: creation, adam

I am reading from the book of Genesis where it is written,

**Genesis 2:20-23 New International Version (NIV)**

> 20 So the man gave names to all the livestock, the birds in the sky
>   and all the wild animals.
>
> But for Adam no suitable helper was found. 21 So the Lord God caused
>   the man to fall into a deep sleep; and while he was sleeping, he took
>   one of the man’s ribs and then closed up the place with flesh. 22 Then
>   the Lord God made a woman from the rib he had taken out of the man,
>   and he brought her to the man.
>
> 23 The man said,
>
> “This is now bone of my bones
>       and flesh of my flesh; she shall be called ‘woman,’
>       for she was taken out of man.”

Taking into account the recent advances in knowledge with regards to "bone marrow", and a procedure that has been introduced into the medical world  nicknamed  [“the Eve procedure.”](https://med.stanford.edu/news/all-news/2010/11/rib-used-to-reconstruct-jaw-at-packard-childrens.html),It would appear that the "rib bone", that was removed from Adam could now be referred to as a "living bone".To help one understand my reasoning,it is written in the book of Ezekiel that,

**Ezekiel 37:1-8 New International Version (NIV)**

**The Valley of Dry Bones**

> 37 The hand of the Lord was on me, and he brought me out by the Spirit
>   of the Lord and set me in the middle of a valley; it was full of
>   bones. 2 He led me back and forth among them, and I saw a great many
>   bones on the floor of the valley, bones that were very dry. 3 He asked
>   me, “Son of man, can these bones live?”
>
> I said, “Sovereign Lord, you alone know.”
>
> 4 Then he said to me, “Prophesy to these bones and say to them, ‘Dry
>   bones, hear the word of the Lord! 5 This is what the Sovereign Lord
>   says to these bones: I will make breath enter you, and you will come
>   to life. 6 I will attach tendons to you and make flesh come upon you
>   and cover you with skin; I will put breath in you, and you will come
>   to life. Then you will know that I am the Lord.’”
>
> 7 So I prophesied as I was commanded. And as I was prophesying, there
>   was a noise, a rattling sound, and the bones came together, bone to
>   bone. 8 I looked, and tendons and flesh appeared on them and skin
>   covered them, but there was no breath in them.

The bones in the above text are referred to as dry bones and they **are not** living bones according to what is written in the text.In other words these bones do not contain any living cells.For more understanding please read [Adam's rib and the origin of stem cells](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ajh.22005/pdf).

It would appear to myself that God formed Eve out of a living bone because of the presence of bone marrow contained in the rib that God surgically removed from Adam.

My question is,

Is it reasonable to refer to Adams rib as a "living bone" ?

*This seems to have great typological significance concerning Christ and the Church.*

Comment: @Ruminator- This question is also helpful. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/22435/does-genesis-221-24-suggest-that-the-woman-shared-adams-breath

Comment: I down-voted this question (I think that it should be removed) because it is an attempt to impose a realistic and technological interpretation on a text that is written in figurative  and symbolic prose including alliterations and allusions to figures of speech. This is like trying to interpret an impressionistic painting from the point of view of the realism movement. It borders on silliness. I suggest investing the time required to acquire fluency in both the language and the historical context of the MT in order to be able to understand that the original does not support such conjecture.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not about the text of scripture. It is attempting to add words to scripture from an outside source - 'recent advances'.

Comment: @NigelJ- I would disagree with you.It is about the text of scripture.Iam not attempting to add words from an outside source.Knowledge has increased, which enables us to understand more about Adams' rib.

Comment: I may not agree that it is "figurative and symbolic prose," but this interpretation is certainly eisegetical and not within the context of the passage. The author(s) and the Hebrew people certainly had no understanding or conception of "the Eve procedure", stem cells, or modern medicine making this squarely off-topic. Clearly the authorial  intent (whether you see the author as Divine, Divinely Inspired or otherwise did not have this in mind in light of target audience.

Comment: @James Shewey-you quote-   The author(s) and the Hebrew people certainly had no understanding or conception of "the Eve procedure", stem cells, or modern medicine making this squarely off-topic.  I am very aware of that.My point is that times have moved on and Today we have much more information regarding the human body which sheds more light on the removal of Adam's rib and what is contained within the rib..Thanks for your feed-back.

Comment: Did God create female animals from the ribs of the male animals?

Answer (score 2):

Original answer followed by the translation supplied by Google Translate:

Original:

> É correto afirmar que o osso da costela de Adão era sim um osso
>   vivo.  Se observarmos atentamente o versículo 21 ( Então, o Senhor
>   Deus fez cair um sono pesado sobre Adão e este adormeceu; e tomou uma
>   de suas costelas e cerrou a carne em seu lugar.) verás que de fato foi
>   retirado não só o osso da costela, mas, também carne. Deus poderia ter
>   feito Eva da mesma maneira que fez Adão, porém, Deus fez questão de
>   usar parte do homem para fazer a mulher, não só pelo proposito de que
>   Adão tivesse uma companheira, mas também como uma ilustração da união
>   de um homem com uma mulher (o casamento), para nos mostrar que homem e
>   mulher estão unidos em uma só carne, para que ambos se completem em um
>   só corpo.

Google Translate:

> It is correct to say that the bone of Adam's rib was a living bone. If
>   we look closely at verse 21 (Then the Lord God caused a heavy sleep to
>   fall upon Adam, and he fell asleep, and took one of his ribs and
>   closed the flesh in his place.) You will see that in fact not only the
>   rib bone , but also meat. God could have made Eve the way Adam did,
>   but God made a point of using part of man to make woman, not only for
>   the purpose that Adam had a mate, but also as an illustration of the
>   union of a man with a woman (the marriage), to show us that man and
>   woman are united in one flesh, so that both may be completed in one
>   body.

Comment: Please post in English on this site. *Gracias*

Comment: Genesis 20: 23 The man said,

“This is now bone of my bones and flesh of my flesh; she shall be called ‘woman,’ for she was taken out of man.” Thanks for your answer.

Comment: For comparison- please read this question and answers' https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20445/in-genesis-224-how-do-a-husband-and-wife-become-one-flesh?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In the scriptural paradigm of the making of Adam man was/is composed of two ingredients:

- clay (sculptable wet dirt)
- the "breath of life"

> NET Bible Genesis 2:7 The LORD God formed the man from the soil of the
>   ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man
>   became a living being.

It is the latter that animates the otherwise lifeless statue of YHVH and gives intelligence, self awareness, etc.

The imparting of breath to Eve is described without God breathing into her suggesting that "the Eve Procedure" was a success.

This may also provide insight into what is meant by this important verse:

> NET Bible Leviticus 17:11 **for the life of every living thing is in the
>   blood**. So I myself have assigned it to you on the altar to make
>   atonement for your lives, for the blood makes atonement by means of
>   the life.

This does not explain why babies do not need breath breathed into them. They receive it from their mothers but they have an independent blood supply.